# Realtime WebApp: Send the same data for all connected clients at the same time

Tags: c#, node.js, sockets, web-applications, websocket

I want to create simple game which data will be send to clients by the server. Clients should have the same data at the same time, data should be generated by the server. If the server returns some rand() value it could be the same for all. It could generate data via interval 24/h every 1minute new value.

Clients excercise is to guess the value which server return, on succes this player win, and new rand starts.

What technology i should to use, it could be web app availible on browsers. I prefer to create it with c# and websockets, but i dont know how to integrate data for all clients.

Help, thanks.

Comment: Why did you flag this with c# and node.js? can you ell us a little more about how your app works (what is Node doing and what are you doing with c#)? If using NodeJS I'd recommend http://socket.io/

Answer (score 0):

Luckily Node provides socket.io library which you can use to achieve this level of functionality.

[Get Socket.io Details](https://www.npmjs.org/package/socket.io)

With socket.io you can broadcast the same data to all connected users using websockets.